# Get latest file based on file name pattern in java

Tags: java

Have file name pattern as YYYYMDD or YYYYMMDD as below.

Have list of files with below pattern in a directory.
Have to read the latest file based on the file name in java. 
How to do this?

```
xxx_2016103
....
xxx_20161104
```

Comment: You should definitely use placeholder zeroes in your dates, which would change `xxx_2016103` to `xxx_20160103`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to fetch the dates, map them to files, and let the fact that [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) objects implement [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) so they are ordered do the work for you.

```
Map<Date,File> filedatemap = new TreeMap<Date,File>();
for(File f : inputdir.listFiles()) { //Assumption: inputdir is a File object pointing to the target directory.
    String filename = f.getName();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");
    Date filedate = df.parse(filename, new ParsePosition(filename.getLastIndexOf('_'));
    filedatemap.put(filedate,f);
}

File latestfile = filedatemap.lastEntry().getValue(); //Last entry because natural order of Date is chronological.
//Go do things with that file
```

For best results, take Zircon's comment to heart and pad your single digit Months/Days with 0 so that that SimpleDateFormat will parse correctly.

Comment: I would create a normal map (Hashmap) then create a treemap from the result after the for loop as adding entry in a treemap is slower than in a hashmap.

Comment: Good Answer. FYI, the troublesome `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` classes are now outmoded, supplanted by the java.time classes. Use `LocalDate` and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your filenames in a list, you can create a custom comparator to sort the list based on the date in the filename.

```
public class FilenamesWithDateSuffixComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static final int ONE_DIGIT_MONTH_FORMAT = "yyyyMdd".length();

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String date1 = o1.substring(o1.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
        String date2 = o2.substring(o2.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
        // If the dates only have one digit for the month, insert a zero.
        if (date1.length() == ONE_DIGIT_MONTH_FORMAT) {
            date1 = date1.substring(0, 4) + "0" + date1.substring(5);
        }
        if (date2.length() == ONE_DIGIT_MONTH_FORMAT) {
            date2 = date2.substring(0, 4) + "0" + date2.substring(5);
        }       
        return date1.compareTo(date2);
    }
}
```

Then, you can sort the list using the comparator:

```
Collections.sort(fileNamesList, new FilenamesWithDateSuffixComparator());
```

Or using the list short method in Java 8:

```
fileNamesList.sort(new FilenamesWithDateSuffixComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a small class `FileDateWrapper` containing `String filename; DateTime date;`
2. Collect all the filenames in a `List<FileDateWrapper>` (leave date null for now)
3. Use some date/time API like [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or `java.time` (Java 8 +) to create two date formats (as you have described)
4. Go through the list, striping off the `_` character (`.split()`) and then attempting to parse the resulting string on both formats (eg. using [parseDateTime(String)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime(java.lang.String)). Store the date that was succesfully parsed in the field of your `FileDateWrapper`
5. Implement `Comparator` or `Comparable` and sort your list of `FileDateWrapper` (or `Collections.max`)